# Inserting image into Image control (ASP.Net)

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, image

I have a `Datalist` inside my form that I used to automatically display images when an image is uploaded by user.

Here is my `Default.aspx` for displaying images:

```
<asp:DataList Width="100%" ID="imgDataList" runat="server" RepeatColumns="4" CellPadding="10">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <table runat="server" id="tblImgList" border="1" width="100%">
            <tr>
                <td align="center">
                    <a id="Link1" runat="server" href='<%# Eval("Value") %>' target="Default.aspx">
                        <asp:Image ID="imgDisp" ImageUrl='<%# Eval("Value") %>' runat="server" style="height :200px ; width :200px ;" />
                    </a> 
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td align="center">
                    <%# Eval("Text") %>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:DataList>
```

For `Image` control, I already set the **height and the width to 200px** so every images that displayed stretched to fit **200px** and it looked not nice. How do I display the image so that it will stay with the original looked? If `Winsform` it use the `Sizemode` property to adjust the picture. How do I adjust it if using `Web form application`?

Comment: Just use only one property, width or height, it will adjust other property automatically based on size of image.

Comment: @emarald , try to use percentage rather that px , so that based on the image it will adjust to the percent of screen but will not stretch

Comment: @Webruster it's true that the image not stretch but those images displayed with a random size. For example I use 15% for both width and height but when displayed the 1st image is 20x50, and 2nd image is 45x25

Comment: @Emerald got it, please check my answer and tell me it worked out or not

Comment: @PiyushKhatri I tried it before setting the `height=200px` and `width=auto` and when image that has a width that wider than the size of my table width, the table width will automatically become wider

Comment: @emarald Its true, based on your design you need to take decision, whether you need to use height or width. So another will be auto. That's the only way to deal with image size. Another solution is to assign width or height from code behind. You can check image size in code behind, if width is more than height, just set width, if height is more than width, just set height. By doing this, you are assigning width or height dynamically and other property will be auto. So there is no any design issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my comment, its always better to use the Percentage rather than px , so that the image will not be stretched.

CSS:

```
img {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    width: auto\9; /* ie8 -because of Bug in ie8 need to give widht the following way */ 
}
```

And if you want to enforce a fixed max width of the image, just place it inside a container, for example:

```
<a style="max-width:500px;">
    <asp:img src="..." />
</a>
```

Comment: I took your solution and edit a bit the max-width. It working fine now. Thanks :)